# Error when failing a state machine: "Value at 'error' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must have length less than or equal to 256"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I have this error in my logs:

```
ValidationException: 1 validation error detected: Value at 'error' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must have length less than or equal to 256
```

I am using AWS Step Functions. What is causing this error?

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by this code:

```
await sfnClient.send(
    new SendTaskFailureCommand({
        taskToken: token,
        error: errorMessage,
    })
)
```

The parameter `error` at [SendTaskFailure](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_SendTaskFailure.html) has a maximum length of 256 characters.